# Cloud function to join files from 2 buckets

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am newbie to GCP, working on a cloud function to unzip a file and join with couple of files from another bucket. I am not sure we can trigger with dataflow because this file arrives every hour.

Input Bucket: test.csv.gz
Staging Bucket: test1.csv
                test2.csv

For now I am trying to unzip the file and copy to staging bucket.
**code to unzip and stage the file:**

```
from google.cloud import storage
import gzip
import shutil
client = storage.Client()
input_bucket = client.get_bucket('INPUT-BUCKET-NAME')
staging_bucket = client.get_bucket('STAGING-BUCKET-NAME')

def unzip_main(data, context):
    with storage.open(''data['name']'', 'r') as f:
      with storage.open('/' + STAGING_BUCKET_NAME + '/' + id, 'w', content_type='text/plain') as fw:
    content = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f).read()
    shutil.copyfileobj(content, f_out)
    f.close()
```

I get compilation errors while deploying, can someone please correct my approach and help me with some pointers to join them

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You can trigger it with a [storage trigger](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--trigger-bucket) for your input bucket

Comment: You should make an effort to clean at least the trivial errors in your code...

Comment: @Dan, I tested the  python code on my local machine but don't know how to merge it with Cloud function. I tried to merge my code with googled code but couldn't figure out where i am  missing, can you please help me in fixing the code.